# How to handle unordered sets of tags in Python Pandas Dataframe in terms of merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, unordered

I have two Dataframes which contain tags in one of the columns. Tags can be present or absent in the list and are stored in an unordered manner. I would like to get the merge of the two datasets with rows that have the same tags. In plain python I can store them as the set datatype.

```
tags1 = {"tag1","tag2"}
tags2 = {"tag2","tag1"}
tags1 == tags2
True
```

However I cant do the same in Pandas since sets are not hashable.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'foo', 'tags': {"tag1","tag2"}}, {'name': 'bar', 'tags': {"tag3","tag4"}}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'name': 'baz', 'tags': {"tag4","tag3"}}, {'name': 'qux', 'tags': {"tag5","tag6"}}])
df1.merge(df2, how="inner", indicator=True, on="tags")
```

What I would like to see

```
     name_x  value           name_y _merge
0    bar     {"tag3","tag4"} baz    both
```

What I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

What would be the best approach here? Unfortunatelly I cant define a fixed amount of columns since the quantity of the tags is not fixed.

Comment: Convert your `set` to `frozenset` which are hashable then `merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset)s and assign to `left_on` and `right_on` parameters if need original `set`s columns:

```
out = (df1.merge(df2, how="inner", indicator=True, 
                left_on=df1['tags'].apply(frozenset),
                right_on=df2['tags'].apply(frozenset)))
print (out)
          key_0 name_x        tags_x name_y        tags_y _merge
0  (tag3, tag4)    bar  {tag3, tag4}    baz  {tag3, tag4}   both
```

Or assign `frozenset`s to `tags` columns:

```
out = (df1.assign(tags=df1['tags'].apply(frozenset))
          .merge(df2.assign(tags=df2['tags'].apply(frozenset)), 
                how="inner", 
                indicator=True, 
                on="tags"))
print (out)
  name_x          tags name_y _merge
0    bar  (tag3, tag4)    baz   both
```